# How to calculate age based on picked date in DatePickerDialog android?

Tags: java, android

How could i do this?

This is my code:

```
private void setDateTimeField () {
    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddBirthday.this, new OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            addBirthdayDate.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            dateSelected = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + " /" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                    + " /" + String.valueOf(year);
        }
    }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

I would like now to calculate when is birthday of user when he chose the date in DatePickerDialog and storing it in integer type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with an easier code like this for example:

```
    private int mDay;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mYear;
    private EditText date;
    private Calendar c = new Calendar();

    ...

    //and in your onCreate method:
    date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date_of_birth_as_text);

    date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID); //DATE_DIALOG_ID is the id of your DatePickerDialog - declared in your layout file

        }
    });

    //default values of the year, month and date - will be changed after click on the EditText view
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    updateDisplay();

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch(id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay); 
        }
        return null;
     }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener= new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            updateDisplay();
        }
    };

private void updateDisplay() {
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    int age = currentDate.getYear() - mYear;
    date.setText( new StringBuilder().append("The user is ")
            .append(age).append(" years old"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but i need calculation for getting an age of person base on date he chose in DatePickerDialog. For example if he chose 1992 year, i need to calculate that to 23 years and store it in integer type.

Comment: take a look at the edit of my post then :) You could calculate and print it like this `Date currentDate = new Date();
    int age = currentDate.getYear() - mYear;`

Comment: * You could get the current year like this too  Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900

Comment: getYear() method is depracted.

Comment: That's why I wrote that you could use `Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900` instead

Answer (score -1):

int age = getCurrentYear() -datePicker.getYear() ;

Comment: This will be buggy in a few weeks.  Better not to hard-code the current year.  It would be good to edit your answer and obtain the current year instead.