# How to calculate age in Android Application using edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am working on an android application that shows bar specials in the area and I want to make sure the only users that are using our app are 21+ years old. I have created a login/registration activity using edit texts and the information typed into the edit texts is sent to a mySQL database.

I have already searched for tutorials on youtube/stack overflow/google for help on this and I have only found datepicker tutorials. I am not sure how I would implement a datepicker tutorial into my project using edit texts.

Here is part of my RegisterActivity.java file that I want to validate the data when the user clicks on register. I have already figured out how to validate email/password but do not know how to add date difference into my code. I have also added my submitForm function that is called....

I am not sure what the output is supposed to look like or how to implement age validation into my project as a I am still fairly new to using Android Studio and I am open to new ideas etc. on how to best implement this into my project.

Here is part of my RegisterActivity.java file that I want to validate the data when the user clicks on register. I have already figured out how to validate email/password but do not know how to add date difference into my code. I have also added my submitForm function that is called....

```
buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String email = signupInputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = signupInputPassword.getText().toString();
                if (password.length()< 8){
                    signupInputPassword.setError("Your password must be at least 8 characters");
                }else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
                    signupInputEmail.setError("You must enter a valid email address");
                } else {

                    submitForm();
                }

            }
        });
```

submitForm()

```
private void submitForm() {

        int selectedId = genderRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        String gender;
        if(selectedId == R.id.female_radio_btn)
            gender = "Female";
        else
            gender = "Male";

        registerUser(signupInputName.getText().toString(),
                signupInputEmail.getText().toString(),
                signupInputPassword.getText().toString(),
                gender,
                signup_input_DOB.getText().toString());
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631453/how-to-calculate-age-based-on-picked-date-in-datepickerdialog-android

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are following a long way to do this task. You can simply use DatePicker ([Android Date Picker Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers)

and set the selection range for the date, set the selected date (by the user) on the TextView. User Interface for handling the click event.

Create Interface.

```
public interface IOnItemClickListenerCountryStates {
    void onAgeClick(String Date);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date of birth on the sign up input from String to Date like this:

```
String DOB = signup_input_DOB.getText().toString(); 

Date dateOfBirth=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(DOB);
```

Then pass the date of birth to a method computing for the age:

```
int age = currentDate.getYear() - dateOfBirth.getYear();
```

Comment: Getting age from years alone is not enough. You need to check month and day too. Your provided answer would be bad if checking for age is for legal reasons.